# Does the Stack Exchange iOS app stop sending notifications for questions that have lots of comments?

Tags: bug, comments, ios-app, notifications

When enabling notifications from within the iOS version of the SE app, I've noticed that whilst the majority of notifications are delivered without issue, any question that I ask that begins to get lots of comments appear to be stopped in some way so that only the first several comments are delivered as notifications. Is this an intentional design decision?

Comment: There is no more development on the apps for a few years already.